# How do I prove that the system is asimptotically stable under a control law?

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am consiering the model of a unicycle in polar coordinates:

$\dot{r}=-vcos\gamma$

$\dot{\gamma}=v\frac{sin\gamma}{r}-\omega$

$\dot{\delta}=v\frac{sin\gamma}{r}$

[image]

where $r$ is the distance from the origin, $\gamma$ is a sort of pointing error, so it is the angle between $\theta$, which is the orientation of the unicycle with respect to the world frame and $r$, and $\delta$ is the orientation at the origin.

with the following velocity inputs inputs:

$v=k_1rcos\gamma$

$\omega=k_2\gamma+k_1\frac{sin\gamma cos\gamma}{\gamma}(\gamma+k_3\delta)$

which is obtained by a Lyapunov argument, choosing the Lyapunov function:

$V=\frac{1}{2}(r^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2)$

and computing its derivative and using the control inpute above, I obtain the following:

$\dot{V}=-k_1cos^2\gamma r^2-k_2\gamma^2<0$

so, these control inputs $v$ and $\omega$ drive the robot to the origin:

[image]

now, I would like to prove mathematically that this control law drives the unicycle to the origin or the cartesian plane, but I have not clear how to do this.

I have seen that it is possible to use the **Barbalat lemma**, which I have not studied in my coruse of studies, and also the **La Salle's Theorem**.

I really don't know how to do this, and it would be really interesting to prove that the control law works.

Can somebody help me?

I will add some papers iin which this problem is used:

- http://www.centropiaggio.unipi.it/sites/default/files/vehicles-RA-MGZ95.pdf
- http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:662268/FULLTEXT01
- [https://people.kth.se/~dimos/pdfs/IET15_Zambelli.pdf](https://people.kth.se/%7Edimos/pdfs/IET15_Zambelli.pdf)

In particular, what I am really interested to prove is what is said in the first paper in the list above, in which says that the only possible point of convergence is $(x,y,\theta)=(0,0,0)$

[EDIT] I am not sure of what I am doing, but I have seen that for the barbalt Lemma I need to have the following conditions:

1. $V$ is lower bounded
2. $\dot{V}$ negative definite
3. $\dot{V}$ continuos

so, am I going in the correct direction? And it seems that the first two conditions are satisfied, but how do I know if the third condition is satisfied?

I have seen that La Salle's Theorem is only for autonomous systems, and I think that this is not my case.

[EDIT]As suggested in the comments, I will use LaSalle Invariance principle to prove asymptotic stability.
This is what I have done so far:

I have plugged the inputs $v$ and $\omega$ into the system, and I obtain:

$\dot{r}=-k_1rcos^2\gamma$

$\dot{\gamma}=k_1rcos\gamma\frac{sin\gamma}{\gamma}-k_2\gamma+k_1\frac{sin\gamma cos\gamma}{\gamma}(\gamma+k_3\delta)$

$\dot{\delta}=k_1cos\gamma sin\gamma$

**$(1)$**

now, I define the set of points in which :

$\dot{V}=-k_1cos^2\gamma r^2-k_2\gamma^2=0$

which is:

$E=(r,\gamma : \dot{V}=0)$

which is the one given by $r=0$ and $\gamma=0$

so, if I plug these values into the system **$(1)$** I obtain:

$\dot{r}=0$

$\dot{\gamma}=0$

$\dot{\delta}=0$

so $M=(0,0,0)$ ,which is the largest invariant set in $E$, and so $(r,\gamma,\delta)->(0,0,0)$ meaning that $r,\gamma$ and $\delta$ tends asimptotically to zero.

can somebody tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Presumably $r$ is distance from the orgin. But what are $\gamma$ and $\delta$ measuring?

Comment: (1) Apparently $r, \gamma, \delta, v, \omega$ are all time-dependent. What about $k_1, k_2$ - do they depend on the other variables or time? Or are they constants? (2) Also, your statement that $\dot V < 0$ apparently assumes that $k_1, k_2 > 0$. Is this known?

Comment: A Lyapunov function must satisfy $V(\mathbf x) = 0 \implies \mathbf x = 0$, but I don't see how that is the case for your function. First of all, you can't even make it dependent on derivatives unless you are treating it as a system of $6$ variables. But even then, $V \ne 0$ does not imply $r = \gamma = \delta = 0$

Comment: @PaulSinclair. Thanks for your answers. $k_1,k_2$ are gains of the system, so are constant that I can choose. Moreover, I took this example from the book "bruno siciliano robotics modelling planning and control", in which literally says:

Comment: $\dot{V} $ is negative definite. As a consequence $V$ tends to a limit value so is bounded. It can also be shown that $\ddot{V}$ is bounded, so $\dot{V}$ is uniformly continuous. So, in view of the Barbalt lemma it can be inferred that $\dot{V}$ tends to zero, and likewise $r$and $\gamma$ converge to zero. With further analysis we can conclude that $\delta$ converges to zero.

Comment: This is the reason why I would like to prove this.

Comment: $\dot V \to 0$ does not imply $r \to 0, \gamma \to 0, \delta \to 0$ by itself. If $(r, \gamma, \delta)$ were a smooth curve on the unit sphere, then $r^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2 = 1$ implies $r\dot r + \gamma\dot\gamma + \delta\dot\delta = 0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair. You are completely right, I wrote my Lyapunov function wrong. So sorry. I have edited the question with the correct one.

Comment: The system is autonomous, thus no problems for LaSalle. However, the system is not properly defined at $r=0$ due to the division, and it is not great since you want to drive $r$ to zero. However, I suppose you can fix it by choosing your control law. What you should do now is to substitute $v$ and $\omega$ in the model and study what are the invariant sets of the cosed-loop autonomous system.

Comment: Sorry if I keep commenting, I have proven with LaSalle as you suggested. But does this mean that $(0,0,0)$ is the only point of convergence?